# API-Call Example with Postman or Fiddler

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I tried the installation with Docker and Kiwi TCMS and it worked wonderfully. Unfortunately, I have a lot of trouble with API calls. I tried several times without success to import the example Perl script from the documentation (https://gist.github.com/atodorov/f5aed028b6f254d97bcaf93453abe8d2).

Does an example(API-Call) exist without a Perl script (for Postman or Fiddler)? I would like to permanently update existing data with .NET environment.
Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

The script in the gist is Python, not Perl.

For .NET I can't help you because I've never written a single line of code in .NET. Maybe somebody else can.

See if you have ready libraries for making XML-RPC calls or JSON-RPC calls. This is very common so I imagine there are such libraries. Then you will need to execute the method names described in out API docs.

In any case if someone is using .NET, or any other language for that matter please contribute your scripts/snippets to https://github.com/kiwitcms/api-scripts so we can build a shared knowledge base.